# How to refer to a yet non-existent bean by using Spring @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I dislike XML configurations (those large and unreadable files) and I prefer using java code instead of them. I'm working with a simple web project based by Spring (Core, MVC) and Thymeleaf as a template engine.

The snippet of code is laid out below.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.github.tobilko"})
public class DependencyConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "templateResolver")
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver getTemplateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();

        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");

        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "templateEngine")
    public SpringTemplateEngine getTemplateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(/*?*/);
        return engine;
    }

}
```

I'm interested in a place that I noted as `/*?*/`. I want to refer to the `templateResolver` bean. *What would I have to paste here? How to refer to a yet non-existent bean?*

An example bean configuration in XML file:

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
       class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
  <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine"
      class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
  <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>
```

The following code

```
engine.setTemplateResolver(
    (ITemplateResolver)
    new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext().getBean("templateResolver")
);
```

throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException`:

> context has not been refreshed yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
public SpringTemplateEngine getTemplateEngine(ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver) {
```

You can inject defined beans into methods which are annotated with `@Bean` or you can call `getTemplateResolver()` inside `getTemplateEngine()`.

Comment: that's damn simple solution, why didn't I find it out immediately? thank you so much